# Reset Workflow Before Starting New one on Item Create

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-history

I have a list of useful contacts which can be added by any user. One of the columns on these list items is `Contact Review Date` - a value which is calculated at [Today]+365 on item creation.

I would like an email to be sent to some user on this date so that they can review the contact and make sure they are still relevant. to this end I have created the following workflow :

[image]

I need this workflow to run each time an item is created (easy) as well as each time a contact is edited (as an edited list item implies that it has been reviewed recently and so we can wait another year for the next review date).

However, as it currently stands this workflow will be kicked off at creation, and then again when the item is modified, meaning that the reviewing user will now receive 2 emails (1 year after creation and 1 year after item modified) :

[image]

Is there a way of somehow removing all other workflows on a list item before starting the current workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by creating 2 workflows associated with the list, one which is started at item creation and one which starts when the item is edited :

**Item Created**

[image]

This workflow sets a workflow status before just waiting until `Contact Review Date` is equal to today. This is somehow more "dynamic" than a `pause until date` action, as any change in the `Contact Review Date` field will now affect the behaviour of this workflow, rather than us having to update the workflow itself when the field changes.

**Item Modified**
[image]

Now when an item is modified, `Contact Review Date` is updated to a year, meaning our `New Item` workflow will only kick off in a year from the item's last modified date.